# Symfony - Validate entity differently in INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I want validate an entity doctrine differently when the entity is created, updated or deleted.

There is an entity constraint validator in my entity class.

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/AcmeEntity.php
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AcmeAssert;

/**
* @AcmeAssert\CustomConstraint
*/
class AcmeEntity
{
    // ...
    protected $name;

    // ...
}
```

In my CustomConstraint I want determine if the Entity will be updated, created or delete for execute a specific validator.

Using unit of work is a solution ?

What is the best way to make this?

I think this problematic is common in lot of application ?

Thank's all ;)

Comment: i suggest you to use the symfony2 validation groups to switch with different constraint validator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either use [validation groups based on the submitted data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html) or handle itwhen you create the form by passing the validation group.
For example, in your controller when you create the form;

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AcmeType(), $acme, ['validation_groups' => ['create']]);
```

Then you entity would be something like;

```
    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=11, groups={"create", "update"})
     * @AcmeAssert\ContainsAlphanumeric(groups={"create"}) // only applied when create group is passed
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Comment: In fact it's more logical to make validation with goups and determine type of validation before execute the Entity validator. Thank's for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

This is what validation groups are made for.

Since Symfony Forms read validations from entity annotations and use internally the Validator component you'd have a look at these articles in the documentation:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html